# Paragraph indent in qml

Tags: qt, qml

I need a way a to adopt property text-indent in my qml code. QML Docs says it's supported, but didn't explain how to use it. I'm trying to run something like that (I tried more variants but failed):

```
    Text{
    width: parent.width
    wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
    textFormat: Text.StyledText
    text: "<text-indent='50px'>Hellow world"
    }
```

But it doesn't work. Qml sees text-indent in code (or it just see "<>") and doesn't show it in the text label, but still didn't activate it.
Maybe this is kinda extra but the same question I can ask about all of tags which I can see in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should change your text format to `Text.RichText` and also use HTML tag and correct CSS style and CSS rules.

Please See [textFormat Doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#textFormat-prop)

> **Text.RichText** supports a larger subset of **HTML 4**, as described on the [Supported HTML Subset page](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html)

```
   Text{
        width: parent.width
       wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
       textFormat: Text.RichText
       text:"<p style=\"text-indent:50px;\">Hello World</p>"
       }
```

**The output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped. Do you know how to keep double space in that case (i mean "   ")? I tried <pre> but it ruins wrapMode. Or may be I should set double space another way.

Comment: @npht your welcome, since it's another question you should ask it in another question. Qml has [double validator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-doublevalidator.html)